# How to create constant space between bars/columns in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

When I say space, I mean not only the space between bars/columns, but also the space between the sides of the chart (y axis and other size). I am looking at this example

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
  },

  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      groupPadding: 0.3,
      pointPadding: 0,
      pointWidth: 20,
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [5, 3, 4]
  }, {
    data: [2, 2, 3]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```

[image: Spacing example]

As you see, there is EQUAL SPACING between 0-1, and 1-2, BUT the spacing it NOT equal between the Y-Axis to 0, and 2 to the right side of the chart (the opposite side of the Y axis). **How do I adjust these? Can I set them to a set pixel padding/margin for between the Y axis and the 0 bar, and similarly to the other side?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `minPadding` and `maxPadding` properties, but their value is relative to the length of the axis.

---

You can also define `pointRange` as `2` and correct ticks by using `tickPositions` or `tickPositioner`:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        pointRange: 2,
        pointWidth: 20,
    }
},
xAxis: {
    maxPadding: 0,
    minPadding: 0,
    tickPositions: [0, 1, 2]
},
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2xdwuah9/

---

Finally, you can reset default margins and specify `min` and `max` for the x-axis:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        pointRange: 0,
        pointWidth: 20,
    }
},
xAxis: {
    maxPadding: 0,
    minPadding: 0,
    min: -1,
    max: 3
},
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/96pw12u0/

---

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minPadding

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointRange

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for your reply. Why does the spacing get removed if we have `categories`?  I added 3 categories and the spacing gets removed from the  pointRange.

http://jsfiddle.net/2c4pLmrn/

Comment: Hi @drewkiimon, With a category axis, you need to use `min` and `max` properties. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yjh7wa81/

Comment: The `min` and `max` solution really helped me! I did `min: -0.5` and `max: categories.length - 0.5`.